Does the # of iterations for which LLVM-MCA is run have an effect on IPC?
If we look at the LLVM MCA Documentation, for the sample example that they've run, "Bottleneck Analysis" says that IPC is limited by resource pressure and not by data dependencies. Here, they run the same block of code for 500 iterations.
But for the same block of code, when it is run for 300 iterations, they say the IPC is mostly limited by data dependencies and not resource pressure. This can be seen at the end of "Extra Statistics to Further Diagnose Performance Issues".
How are they arriving at 2 different conclusions for different iterations ? Shouldn't the result be the same? Please help me make sense of the statistics presented.
Also, if you try to run LLVM-MCA for the same example code, for 300 iterations, it presents a similar number.
Result for 300 iterations

They used a different CPU model (AMD Jaguar) that had a FP PRF big enough to satisfy the register pressure.

I think not. In both the examples, they are using the same CPU Microarchitecture - AMD Jaguar and the codename for it is "btver2". This is specified in the -mcpu option.

Fun fact: AMD Bobcat/Jaguar are the only x86 uarches where phadd* / haddps/pd are single-uop (or 2 on bobcat since the SIMD ALUs are only 64 bits wide).  On other uarches, [v]haddps is at least 3 uops, like 2 shuffles to feed a vertical add.  More on some uarches for some unknown reason!  https://agner.org/optimize/  So on most other uarches, it costs a lot of shuffle throughput, but also has bad latency.
